# Carbon returns bad time

Tags: laravel

I want create a datetime of a bbdd date and bbdd time saved.

This is my controller:

```
    public function indexAjax(Request $request)
    {
        $asesorias = Asesoria::where('user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)
                        ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();        

        foreach($asesorias as $asesoria)
        {            
            $datetime = Carbon::create($asesoria->date, $asesoria->time);
            $events[] = array('title' => $asesoria->place, 'start' => $datetime, 'end' =>$datetime, 'url' => $asesoria->id);

        }

        dd(json_encode($events));
        return  json_encode($events);
    }
```

When create datetime date is correct, but time always returns 0.

This is my dd(json_enconde($events) view:

```
[{"title":"Centro Comercial Las Huertas Av. de Madrid, 37, Palencia","start":"2020-02-03T00:00:00.000000Z","end":"2020-02-03T00:00:00.000000Z"}]
```

In my bbdd time is store:

[image]

What is happening?Why always in my records time are 00:00:00.000000Z?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Carbon::create` doesn't accept date and time as two separate arguments.

It's signature is:

```
Carbon::create($year = 0, $month = 1, $day = 1, $hour = 0, $minute = 0, $second = 0, $tz = null)
```

`Carbon::parse($asesoria->date . ' ' . $asesoria->time)` would probably work, but you're really better off combining date and time in the database into a single `datetime` column, which will let you use Laravel's native datetime handling without issues.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the way Carbon::create works...

Use `Carbon::parse($asesoria->date . ' ' . $asesoria->time)`

You can format the date after that with format() or formatLocalized.

This is pretty clear on the [documentation](https://carbon.nesbot.com/) btw